# Microsoft.OpenApi.Extensions Enum.GetDisplayName() doesn't work, works fine when copied over

Tags: c#, .net, enums, extension-methods

Wanting a quick way to set a display for Enums without creating an enum class, I came across `[Display(Name = "display name")]`
I was going to write my own method but found `Microsoft.OpenApi.Extensions.EnumExtensions.GetDisplayName`.

```
public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enumValue)
{
    var attribute = enumValue.GetAttributeOfType<DisplayAttribute>();
    return attribute == null ? enumValue.ToString() : attribute.Name;
}
```

It doesn't work, returning the `enum.ToString()` value, but if I copy over the method as is into my project, it works fine. Any idea why? Running .net 5.0
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They check for their own [`Microsoft.OpenApi.Attributes.DisplayAttribute`](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET/blob/649f0b1780c575c4780f4091eedd7a555e8ccc4a/src/Microsoft.OpenApi/Attributes/DisplayAttribute.cs).

Either roll your own extension method, pointing to `Systems.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute`, or (less preferably) apply their `DisplayAttribute` to your enum.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I missed that on the usings `Microsoft.OpenApi.Attributes` on the extensions  vs the auto imported `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` when I copied it over. I see the OpenApi one is internal so cannot be used.

Comment: I can't see a reason why they've rolled their own.

Comment: Hi! I have opened a issue on ms repo to change this extension to public, and was accept. https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET/issues/889

Comment: Nice, so now you can finally apply the latter part of my answer. :P